# How to add additional criteria to re.findall ... Python 2.7?

Tags: python, regex, findall

```
ORF_sequences = re.findall(r'ATG(?:...){9,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',sequence)  #thanks to @Martin Pieters and @nneonneo
```

I have a line of code that finds any instance of A|G followed by 2 characters and then ATG that is then followed by either a TAA|TAG|TGA when read in units of 3. only works when A|G-xx-ATG-xxx-TAA|TAG|TGA is 30 elements or greater

i want to add a criteria

i need the ATG to be followed by a G

**so A|G-xx-ATG-Gxx-xxx-TAA|TGA|TAG   #at least 30 elements long**
    example:
    GCCATGGGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGA
    ^ would work

```
GCATGAGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGA
^ would not work because it is an (A|G) followed by only one value (not 2) before the ATG and there is not a G following the A|G-xx-ATG
```

i hope this makes sense

I tried

```
ORF_sequences = re.findall(r'ATGG(?:...){9,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',sequence)
```

but it seemed like it was using window size 3 after last G of ATGG

basically I need that code, where the first occurrence is A|G-xx-ATG and the second occurrence is (G-xx)

Comment: sorry i thought i approved of one of the answers a while ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be easier if you use a character group of `[AG]`, there is no need to group the two 'free' characters:

```
 ORF_sequences2 = re.findall(r'[AG]..ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',fdna)
```

or you need to group the `A|G`:

```
 ORF_sequences2 = re.findall(r'(?:A|G)..ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',fdna)
```

Applying the first form to your examples:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[AG]..ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)', 'GCCATGGGGTTTTGA')
['GCCATGGGGTTTTGA']
>>> re.findall(r'[AG]..ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)', 'GCATGGGGTTTTGA')
[]
```

In your attempt, the expression matches either an `A`, or the expression `G(?:..)ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)` because the `|` symbol applies to *everything* that preceeds or follows it within the same group. As it is not grouped, it applies to the whole expression instead:

```
>>> re.findall(r'A|G(?:..)ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)', 'A')
['A']
>>> re.findall(r'A|G(?:..)ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)', 'GCCATGGGGTTTTGA')
['GCCATGGGGTTTTGA']
```

If you need to match a certain amount of characters in your whole match, you need to tailor those 3 character `(?:...)` groups to match a minimum number of times:

```
 ORF_sequences2 = re.findall(r'[AG]..ATGG..(?:...){7,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',fdna)
```

would match `A` or `G` followed by 2 characters, followed by `ATGG` with another 2 characters, then *at least* 7 times 3 characters (total 21), followed by a specific pattern of 3 more (`TAA`, `TAG` or `TGA`) for a total of at least 33 characters from the first to the last character. The extra `..` make up the pattern of 3 after `ATG` and matches your example from your comment:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[AG]..ATGG..(?:...){7,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)', 'GCCATGGGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGA')
['GCCATGGGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGA']
```

as well as correctly handling the examples given in your question:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[AG]..ATGG..(?:...){7,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)', 'GCCATGGGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGA')
['GCCATGGGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGA']
>>> re.findall(r'[AG]..ATGG..(?:...){7,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)', 'GCATGAGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGA')
[]
```

Comment: thank you! I understand the difference between [AG] and A|G now . i'm sorry but I forgot to add another feature in the function that I will update right now.  after the first ATG there must be a G but if i try re.findall(r'[AG]..ATGG(?:...){9,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)','GCCATGGGGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGA') it doesn't work because it uses the window size 3 after that last G . i'll explain it better in the question above

Comment: You can just do `ATGG..(?:...){8,}` then.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure you get at least 30 characters, use the `{n,}` quantifier:

```
r'[AG]..ATG(?:...){9,}?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)'
```

This ensures that you read at least 9 triplets (27 characters) between the ATG opening and the TAA|TGA|TAG terminator.

Comment: awesome idea! i didn't know that you could do that